# How to get the selected value of combo in Spring MVC 3?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using the Spring MVC `<form:select>` tag in my JSP and have populated the values in it.

How can I retrieve the selected value from the select box and use it for further operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain them in the controller to which you submit. For example:

```
@RequestMapping("/submit")
public String handle(@RequestParam Foo selectedFoo) {
}
```

This assumes you have a converter from `String` to `Foo`. Otherwise you can simply use `String` as argument.

If you want to get the whole form submitted to a javabean, make a bean with fields named exactly the same as the fields in your html form, and pass it as argument to the handling method.

Answer (score 1):

I think this tutorial will help you:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/

Spring MVC 3 example:

http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/web/spring-3-mvc-form-example.html

Just combine the logic from these 2 examples and you will understand hoe to do it right.

Comment: hi danny,

thanks but the tutorial is with reference to Spring 2 , and I am using Spring 3.
Can you please help me with a link for Spring 3